# Correlation on Python

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have the following dataframe:

```
    StockId Date    Value
    1       2015-01-02  -0.070012
    2       2015-01-02  -0.022447
    4       2015-01-02  -0.011474
    6       2015-01-02  0.003796
    13      2015-01-02  -0.032061
    ...
    355     2018-09-14  -0.035717
    356     2018-09-14  -0.007899
    357     2018-09-14  0.065217
    358     2018-09-14  0.063536
    359     2018-09-14  -0.023433
```

---

I'm looking to find the correlation between stocks over time in order to find the five stocks that are most correlated with stock 1. Is there a quick way to do this using pandas? Or does this require creating arrays and then calculating the correlations one by one? There are 359 stocks in the data frame.

Comment: Are your first few rows missing a column? The dataframe seems to jump from 3 to 4 columns. If so, can you update the column headers. Also, what is shape of your dataframe?

Comment: Apologies - no missing column, I am just omitting the indices. The shape is around 2555 x 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is in a long format where each stock is valued once per day, you can use the [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) function to reshape into a wide format. Specify `Date` to be the index of the new dataframe and `StockID` to be the columns. If you have data that is sampled more than daily, you can specify the `aggfunc` argument to be min/max/avg or whatever else you deem appropriate for your application. If you have data that is sampled less than daily, you can still run the code, but be aware that the correlation will be based on some null values.

Note: I'm only saying daily because that's what your table seems to imply.

From there you can use [`df.corr()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) to view the correlation matrix.

```
df = df.pivot(index='Date', columns='StockID')
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()  # Convert multi-index to single index
print(df)
# StockID           a         b         c
# Date
# 1/10/2020  0.956625  0.175345  0.999375
# 1/11/2020  0.458859  0.714604  0.995440
# 1/12/2020  0.603331  0.881022  0.215262
# 1/13/2020  0.584198  0.303796  0.332117

matrix = df.corr()
print(matrix)
# StockID         a         b         c
# StockID                              
# a        1.000000 -0.680290  0.305365
# b       -0.680290  1.000000 -0.336229
# c        0.305365 -0.336229  1.000000
```

From there, you could iterate through each row, sort the row by values, and then you'll have a dict sorted by the strongest correlation.

```
for stock, corr in matrix.to_dict().items():
    corr = {
        k: v for k, v
        in sorted(corr.items(), key=lambda item: -item[1])
        if k != stock
    }
    print(stock, corr)
# a {'c': 0.30536503121224934, 'b': -0.6802897760166712}
# b {'c': -0.3362290204607999, 'a': -0.6802897760166712}
# c {'a': 0.30536503121224934, 'b': -0.3362290204607999}
```

Or, if you want a more visual comparison,

```
plt.matshow(matrix)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly, I don't have each stock valued once per day. When I run the command I get: "None of ['StockID'] are in the columns". Some of them are valued each day, others are not.

Comment: I noticed `StockID` in my code is `StockId` in your code. Are the stocks valued more frequently or less frequently than one day? The pivot funciton has a `aggfunc` argument that could be used.

Comment: If I want to visualize only one stock from the correlation matrix, how do I substitute the print(stock, corr) command?

Comment: That depends on how you want to visualize it. If you've already pivoted the data, you could do `df[[stock_id]].plot()` assuming you've imported `matplotlib`, you could then use `plt.show()`

Comment: Thanks! If I want to see only one stock (stock 1) from the correlation matrix (to see how it is correlated with the other stocks), how do I do? matrix[[1]] is not working.

Comment: It might be better to view the whole matrix. See the image i added to the answer.

Comment: Uhm, I have 359 stocks. I need to see how stock 1 moves with the other 358. A visualization won't do because wouldn't tell me what the 10 stocks that 1 comoves the most with. I tried running matrix['1'] but it was unsuccessful...

Comment: Then please see the code segment with `matrix.to_dict()` where I then sorted the stocks by correlation score.

Comment: By running that command, I obtain the correlation of stock X with the other stocks. How do I select only stock X to appear in my output? Let's say I want to see only how stock 150 comoves with the others.